# How to completely uninstall a Django app?

Tags: python, django, uninstallation, django-apps, drop-table

What is the procedure for completely uninstalling a Django app, complete with database removal?

Comment: remove that app name from settings.py installed apps, then remove any link to that app from main urls.py file. Then u can safely delete that app

Comment: If you're in development using SQLite and you don't mind resetting the database, is it okay to just remove the app folder and `db.sqlite3`, and remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

1. Django < 1.7 has a handy management command that will give you the necessary SQL to drop all the tables for an app. See the [sqlclear docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#sqlclear-appname-appname) for more information. Basically, running `./manage.py sqlclear my_app_name` gets you get the SQL statements that should be executed to get rid of all traces of the app in your DB. You still need to copy and paste (or pipe) those statements into your SQL client. For Django 1.7 and up, use `./manage.py migrate my_app_name zero` (see the [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#migrate) docs), which runs the database cleaning automatically.
2. To remove the app from your project, all you need to do is remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` in your project's `settings.py`. Django will no longer load the app.
3. If you no longer want the app's files hanging around, delete the app directory from your project directory or other location on your PYTHONPATH where it resides.
4. (optional) If the app stored media files, cache files, or other temporary files somewhere, you may want to delete those as well. Also be wary of lingering session data that might be leftover from the app.
5. (optional) I would also remove any stale content types.

Like so.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
for c in ContentType.objects.all():
    if not c.model_class():
        print "deleting %s"%c # print(f"deleting {c}") # for Python 3.6+
        c.delete()
```

Comment: Excellent answer, just one addition that I'd make: pip uninstall package-name is your friend, much nicer than trawling around your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: On Django 1.7, if you use migration, step 1 will be ```./manage.py migrate my_app_name zero```. And it will automatically execute the SQL as well.

Comment: In this post http://www.marinamele.com/how-to-correctly-remove-a-model-or-app-in-django explain hot wo delete models and apps in Django. It's great together with this answer.

Comment: `sqlclear` was removed in Django 1.9 so this answer is only good for previous versions. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9

Comment: If the app being deleted has migrations, which other app's migrations depend on, the migration system will break down when it sees that those dependent migrations no longer exist. Be careful when using the above answer if the app to be deleted is a dependency in the migration history of another one of your apps.

Comment: And for completeness, you'll typically  need to remove a reference to  `include("appname.urls")` from the project's `urls.py`

Comment: I'm using Django 2.2, you can use `python manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes` for step 5

Answer (score 27):

In my context the projects exists several times: I have a development system, some team mates have a development system, there is a staging system for the customer and a production system. This means I don't want to execute sql commands by hand. I want it to be automated.

Goal: Remove the app and all database tables.

#### Step 1: empty the app, but leave it installed

remove all files from the app, except the folder "migrations"

Execute this command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations -n drop_all_tables my_app_to_remove
```

The directory looks now like this:

```
my_app_to_remove/
my_app_to_remove/__init__.py
my_app_to_remove/migrations
my_app_to_remove/migrations/0001_initial.py
my_app_to_remove/migrations/....
my_app_to_remove/migrations/0030_drop_all_tables.py
my_app_to_remove/migrations/__init__.py
```

Leave `my_app_to_remove` in the file "settings.py".

#### Step 2: Deploy the changes

Update all projects. Tell the team mates to update their project and to run the migrations.

#### Step 3: remove "my_app_to_remove" from settings.py

Now remove "my_app_to_remove" from settings.py and deploy again.

Comment: Indeed, good answer on how to get this deployed when you have things automated

Comment: Also beware that you will need to keep any functions/methods that your migrations depend on,  e.g. if you use a function as [field default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#default). Migrations work with [historical models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#historical-models), which do not include custom model methods, etc.

Comment: This is really great (+1), enables migrations to just move forward.

Answer (score 20):

1. comment out on `settings.py` in `INSTALLED_APPS` unnecessary app's line
2. delete all folder `__pycache__` and `migrate` at your project
3. delete unnecessary model in `models.py`
4. delete all *import* link in `views.py`, `admin.py` end etc.
5. delete all link's in `urls.py` on your unnecessary app's
6. in database delete unnecessary tables wich associated with the app (I do it with help program "Valentina Studio")
7. delete app's folder
8. in command line do it: `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 5):

As a first step, prevent any usage of the app models and deploy. This is essential for rolling deployment. Check notes below.

Then you have two options.

**Option 1**

1. (Manual) Run `python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero`. This will revert all the migrations for the app and clean the `django_migrations` table
2. Remove app (code, `INSTALLED_APPS`, `urls.py`, etc.)
3. Deploy (`python manage.py migrate`)

**Option 2**

1. Remove all models in the app
2. Deploy
3. Remove the app (code, `INSTALLED_APPS`, `urls.py`, etc.)
4. Deploy
5. (Manual) Clean `django_migrations` table

This answer is thinking in an automated rolling deployment context (e.g. Heroku).
Manual means it normally cannot be done in automated deployment. Deploy basically refers to `python manage.py migrate` which is normally done in automated deployment.

**Notes**

1. Make sure to remove code importing this app from other apps. Also any references in `settings.py` (but keep it in `INSTALLED_APPS` so we can run migrations), `urls.py`, etc.
2. `migrate <app_name> zero` will revert all migrations depending on those migrations. So be careful if your other apps migrations depend on these migrations.
3. Also be aware of cascade delete if you have not just schema migrations but also data migrations.
4. Signal receivers receiving signals defined in other apps might be an issue in rolling deployment.

**References**

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#migrate

Comment: Thanks @shao. Can you comment on how to do option 2 step 5: (Manual) Clean django_migrations table?

Comment: Hi @BrettElliot, something like `DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app = <your_app_name>;`

Answer (score 4):

django app is a "set" of *.py files and a directory with a django-app-name. So you can simply delete the whole folder with all *.py files

To "remove" tables from DB you should use `DELETE FROM <app-name_table-names>`

Furthermore, you have to delete lines witgh app-name from setting.py in a root directory

Comment: Assuming you aren't sharing the database with another app you can just drop the db named in settings.py.

Comment: each app has own db - not bad

Comment: @V-Light each app has its own table and each project has its own database.

Answer (score 4):

[Safely Remove a Django app by Jordan Haines](https://tldlife.com/safely-removing-a-django-app-17bdb2803200)

To completely remove a Django app (with models), follow the steps below. Let’s pretend we’re removing an app called `note_app`:

1. Search through your other apps for any note_app imports. The easiest way to do this is a project-wide search for “from note_app”. You may want to exclude the note_app directory from your search.
2. Comment out all models in `note_app.models`. You may need to also remove entries from `note_app.admin` file if you registered your note_app models with Django admin.
3. Look for and resolve errors when trying to run your Django app. P.S. You may have missed some model imports in step 1.
4. Note that depending on how you define *ForeignKey, OneToOne* and *ManyToMany* fields, you may have missed some keys to your note_app models in step 1. It’s important that any fields that point to note_app models from models in other apps need to be deleted before you continue. Take a minute to make sure none of these fields were missed; if they were, then delete those fields that remain and create migrations that will remove the fields from your database.
5. Run `makemigrations`. This should create a note_app migration that deletes all of the models you just commended out. This migration should also remove fields referring to note_app models from models in other apps.
6. Run your migrations. You must run your migrations in all environments (including production) BEFORE you delete the app directory. The migrations that remove your app’s models from the database will be — surprise — in your note_app directory. If you delete the app directory prematurely, you will delete these migrations before they have a chance to clean up your database.
7. You may get a notice that the content types for your deleted models are stale. When asked whether or not you want to delete these content types, reply “yes”
8. `Git` Tip: Commit your migrations, take note of the commit, and then create a separate commit that deletes the note_app directory. When you are ready to apply your changes in a staging or production environment, checkout the commit you noted, run the migration, and then checkout the latest commit to delete the app directory. Your first commit should still have note_app in INSTALLED_APPS.
9. Delete the directory that contains the note_app.
10. Remove `note_app` from your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

And that’s really about it…super easy :)

Answer (score 0):

These 3 steps below can completely remove an app from a Django project:

1. Migrate an app with [zero](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate) by specifying it as shown below. *This command below drops all the tables of an app from database:

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero
```

> - <app_label> <migrationname>: Brings the ... app name.  Use the name zero to migrate all the way back i.e. to revert all applied migrations for an app.

*Be careful, you cannot migrate multiple apps with `zero` by specifying them as shown below, then there is an error:

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> <app_name> zero
```

2. Remove the app from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # "my_app",
]
```

3. Delete the app folder from a Django project.

Answer (score 0):

Prior answers are mostly variations on:  https://patrick.cloke.us/posts/2020/01/23/cleanly-removing-a-django-app-with-models/

Django now documents a "sanctioned" method for deleting an app:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/delete-app/

Combined with script below, this solution...

1. can be scripted to run during deployment;
2. completely removes all traces of the app from DB and code base;
3. uses Django API rather than dropping to raw SQL for cleanup.

This process is completed in 2 phases.

Phase 1: delete app models, migrate, and deploy...

- follow "official" django procedure above.
- Note: prior to first deployment, you can remove all app code
  except models (empty), migrations, and apps (needed for deployment)

Phase 2: remove all traces from DB and app package from code base at some future date...

- run the script below to remove all traces of the app model(s) and content type(s) from DB.
- Note: a little cleanup of migrations may be required to get them to all reverse to zero.

A complete management command for Step 2:
https://gist.github.com/powderflask/f0ae8b9ae6c7bb471f591de5175204cd

The heart of that command:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.core.management import call_command

app_label = 'APP_LABEL_TO_DELETE'  # PARAMETER: the app to be removed

content_types = ContentType.objects.filter(app_label=app_label).all()
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type_id__in=content_types)
log_entries = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type_id__in=content_types)

# reverse migrations to remove model DB tables and migrations entries
call_command('migrate', app_label, 'zero')

# delete the content type related data
log_entries.delete()
permissions.delete()
content_types.delete()
```

Comment: Maybe the `migrate --prune` operation can be used to eliminate unused migrations after the app is deleted instead of reversing migrations to zero?  Anyone know?