# What's the proper way to remove a Django app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, django-migrations, django-1.8

I am doing some clean up on an old project. The project has been upgraded to Django 1.8. The project has several apps that are no longer needed at all. I'd like to remove these apps.

The problem is that you can't remove an app with migrations because other apps' migrations might depend on them. For instance...app `car` can be removed, but a model in app `user` has a foreign key to a model in `car`. If I remove the `car` app then I will get errors when the full migrations run. A migration in `user` depends on a migration in `car` (the migration that creates the Car model) and it will fail.

I can go back and edit the `user` migrations to remove all instances of `car`, acting as if it never existed. But then I can't have a migration that removes the `car` property on `User`, so that column will just remain in the database table (even though it is no longer used).

How am I supposed to remove this app without borking my migrations and leaving old columns laying around?

Comment: i hope this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329773/django-how-to-completely-uninstall-a-django-app

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you need to [squash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) your migrations. Here's an outline of what you could do (only as far as migrations are concerned):

1. Add a migration that removes the dependency of `user` on `car`.
2. Squash the migrations of the `user` app.
3. Look at the new squashed migration – if it optimized the foreign key to `car` away, that's perfect, otherwise, remove the foreign key from the squashed migration history manually.
4. Make a release with both new migrations (the one that removes the foreign key, as well as the squashed one).
5. After all deployments have been upgraded (or after a reasonable deprecation cycle), remove the original chain of migrations, leaving only the squashed one behind.