# How to discard a section

Tags: python, django

I want to know how I can remove blog app from my portfolio project using Django and python. Can someone please guide me with the process?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: How to completely uninstall a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329773/django-how-to-completely-uninstall-a-django-app)

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py , there will be installed apps option . Remove your `blog` app from it and delete the app folder from project.

If you want to uninstall a module (like Pillow) just do , `pip uninstall your_module_name`